# show several curve fit output in one diagram python

Tags: python, plot

I have 4 float arrays with sizes `(5,10)` and I need to show each row of these arrays in one diagram. I fit a curve to each row of these arrays. the output is as follows. for the first row, I have 4 graphs as follows. but I need to show all of them in one graph to find the intersection points. I used the following code to produce this graph for each row of arrays. I can do this in Matlab but I do not know how can I show them in one graph in python:

```
y=center_1080[4,:]
x=np.arange(0,10)
popt, _ = curve_fit(objective, x, y)
# summarize the parameter values
a, b, c = popt
print('y = %.5f * x + %.5f * x^2 + %.5f' % (a, b, c))
# plot input vs output
pyplot.scatter(x, y)
# define a sequence of inputs between the smallest and largest known inputs
x_line = arange(min(x), max(x), 1)
# calculate the output for the range
y_line = objective(x_line, a, b, c)
# create a line plot for the mapping function
pyplot.plot(x_line, y_line, '--', color='red')
pyplot.show()
```

[image]

this graph show the real values of first row of 4 arrays in Matlab before curve fitting. I need some thing like this in python to show the output of all curve fit in one diagram:
[image]

Comment: if you call `plt.plot` several times, python will assign to each plot a different color and different legend. Take a look at https://matplotlib.org/2.1.1/tutorials/introductory/usage.html#sphx-glr-tutorials-introductory-usage-py

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a multi-dimensional array to plot and each column will be created as a separate plot object. We transpose both inputs so that it will plot each row separately.

Assuming your (5,10) array looks like this.

```
#d=    [[16 18 29 22 24 26 28 30]
     [17 19 20 24 27 29 29 29]
     [10 18 19 28 29 32 33 36]
     [17 19 22 24 27 28 29 33]]


import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

lineObjects=plt.plot(d.T)
plt.legend(iter(lineObjects), ('360p', '540p', '720p','1080'))
plt.show()
```

If you want to pass more than 2

```
lineObjects=plt.plot(d.T, Arra2.T, Arra3.T..)
```

That's it no need loops anything.

[image]